# increase total supply of TRC20 token daily

Tags: token, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, tron

I want to issue a token on Tron blockchain and I got it's template from the address below :
https://github.com/TRON-Developer-Hub/TRC20-Contract-Template

The problem is that I want to set my token to automatically mint a specified number of tokens daily. (For example mint 2000 tokens per day)

What should I add to the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a functionm, below like that.
But you have to excute mintDaily() manually

```
    uint256 constant private dailyMinted = 2000e18;
    uint256 lastMintTime;

    address public _owner;
    
    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint8 decimals,
        address owner
    ) public {
        _name = name;
        _symbol = symbol;
        _decimals = decimals;

        _owner = owner;
        lastMintTime = block.timestamp;
    }
    
    function mintDaily() public {
        require(_owner == msg.sender, "not permitted");
        // 24h = 86400
        require(lastMintTime + 86400 >= block.timestamp, "mint already" );
        _mint(msg.sender, dailyMinted);
        lastMintTime = block.timestamp;
    }
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for answering. One question: Do you mean that I need to recall mintDaily() function manually every day ?

Comment: There is a problem in the code : `require(lastMintTime + 86400 >= block.timestamp, "mint already" );` must be like this : `require(lastMintTime + 86400 <= block.timestamp, "mint already" );` and lastMintTime = block.timestamp; in mintDaily() must be like this : `lastMintTime += 86400;` (Just noted this for future readers.) Thank you very much for answering my questions.